# Problems with Selenium WebDriver executeScript (using watir-webdriver in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, legacy-code, page-object-gem

I am having trouble executing a particular javascript snippet using Watir WebDriver's browser.execute_script command:

Here is the Javascript in question:

```
  var bodyFrame = document.getElementsByName("BodyFrame")[0];
  var bodyFrameDoc = bodyFrame.contentDocument || bodyFrame.contentWindow.document;
  var mainFrame = bodyFrameDoc.getElementById("MainFrame");
  var mainFrameDoc = mainFrame.contentDocument || mainFrame.contentWindow.document;
  var row = mainFrameDoc.getElementById("DETAIL_1");
  var rowNodes = row.childNodes;
  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < rowNodes.length; index++) {

        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID1') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'ACCRUL';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID2') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'OP';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID3') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'Z';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID4') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'FIRST';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID5') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'AUT';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID6') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'AU1000';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID7') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'm tax m entity m jc';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID8') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'MR5001100';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID9') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = 'T';
        }


        if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === 'ID10') {
            rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = '453.36';
        }

  }
```

Why must I use such an atrocity? Well, because the product I am developing tests for is that bad. Each cell uses the same id attribute, so I cannot directly zone in on the object in the document. To make matters worse, the document is in two frames deep. Frameception.

Using the obvious solution (using watir-webdriver's API) is not feasible, since the task of filling in 32 grid rows is taking one-half!! of an hour.

I can get the Javascript above to run in the browser's developer tools. (The only browsers supported by this product are IE8, 9, in compatibility mode.) I don't have access to jQuery or any fancy javascript library. Using this javascript fills in the rows almost instantly.

When I run this using the browser.execute_script command, I get a

```
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: JavaScript error
```

Curiously enough, if I just used

```
  return document.getElementsByName("BodyFrame")[0];
```

Then I get an error with the Net::HTTP library, which is used by Selenium somewhere on the stack for sending commands back and forth to the browser. (More specifically: ERRNO::ERRCONNREFUSED)

Help?

EDIT: Here's the direct script that I am using to execute the code (and generate the small bit of Javascript):

```
    def quick_fill(data = {})
      reference_element.focus;
      quick_filler = ->(element_id, value) {
        "if (rowNodes[index].firstChild.id === '#{element_id}') {
           rowNodes[index].firstChild.value = '#{value}';
         }"
      }
      row_id = row.attribute(:id)
      element_ids = Hash[data.keys.map { |key| [key, send("#{key}_element").attribute(:id)] }]
      javascript = <<-JAVASCRIPT
      var bodyFrame = document.getElementsByName("BodyFrame")[0];
      var bodyFrameDoc = bodyFrame.contentDocument || bodyFrame.contentWindow.document;
      var mainFrame = bodyFrameDoc.getElementById("MainFrame");
      var mainFrameDoc = mainFrame.contentDocument || mainFrame.contentWindow.document;
      var row = mainFrameDoc.getElementById("DETAIL_1");
      var rowNodes = row.childNodes;
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < rowNodes.length; index += 1) {
        #{element_ids.map { |method, element_id| quick_filler.call(element_id, data[method]) }.join("\n") }
      }
      JAVASCRIPT
      puts javascript
      sleep(0.500)
      browser.execute_script(javascript)
    end
```

The data argument to this method is a hash of key-value pairs, where keys are the names of the methods provided to the page object accessors, and the values are the values I'm trying to fill in. As part of the intermediate process, I get the id element from the page object element (which is provided as the identifier each element).

There is a bit of a peculiar structure going on with how the page class is set up: Here's the basic idea:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  table(:some_table, ...)

  def add_line_item(data = {})
    GridRow.new(some_table_element.last_row, browser).quick_fill(data)
  end

  class GridRow
    include PageObject

    #page object accessors
    text_field(:my_field) { row.text_field_element(id: 'ID1') }
    #etc

    def quick_fill(data = {})
      #see above
    end

    def initialize(row, browser, visit = false)
      @row = row
      super(browser, visit) 
    end
  end
end
```

So the example call will be (from a cucumber test)

```
on_page(MyPage) do |page|
  page.add_line_item(:my_detail => 'myValue')
end
```

In addition to this, there's the unfortunate problem that there are several 'attach_window' calls needed to get to this page (due to the page sitting in a modal dialog of sorts). The issue may be largely related to this interaction. This is the only thing that I can think of that will cause a problem.

The point of this SO question is to hopefully just have a second set of eyes who can rule out any obvious errors. I have another workaround that I'm planning on employing.

Comment: If you are only testing Internet Explorer, why not use the 'watir-classic' gem? Using watir-classic should allow you to execute that code directly without using the `execute_script` method.

Comment: Part of the reason is that we use the page-object gem on top of the watir-webdriver, for nice looking page class interactions, and this is nice for most automation needs for simple, "happy paths". Unfortunately, there's a couple of instances where more data is needed to fully test a basic path, and this is where I'm trying to look to Javascript. Perhaps I can take a look at the 'watir-classic' gem.

Comment: How are you running the `execute_script` method? I just tried with the one line and I did not get any exception.

Comment: I've added more information to how the method is called above.

Comment: as an aside is there no requirement that your pages be HTML standards compliant and be valid HTML?  ID values duplicated within a page are invalid HTML.  If they don't care about testability (which they obviously do not, your time apparently has little value to them it would appear) then do they care about standards?

Comment: I've seen a couple of webdriver errors lately that end up with that connection refused stuff..    What environment are you running the scripts on?

Comment: I'm amazed the native API stuff was taking that long, but maybe that is another question?  could you maybe share a sample of that HTML and what you were trying to do?  maybe there is an faster way to fill in the values you want in the specific cells than what you were trying to do?

Comment: Connection refused errors are hard to debug unless all the environment is provided. Also, +1 for Chuck comment as you can achieve the same result using Watir API and there is no need to use Javascript.